# How to query one particular month data over years in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to query a month report over multiple years
Eg : If we take month of August then I need to query same month report over 100+years

My Data Looks Like below

```
Row Country AverageTemperature    dt
1   Spain   18                   1836-08-01 00:00:00 UTC
2.  Germany 19                   1834-05-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: use Month function of sql `select * from data where Month(date) = 8`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#extract):

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt) = 8
```